# Removing white space from an array containing String in Java

Tags: java

So how can I remove a space(s) from an array of a string...

Taking an example, I have a string called `list`:

String[] list ={"Apple ",  "Mel on", "  Ice -cream ", Television"};

Can anyone please guide on what methods I should be using?
I've already tried using `.replace()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [trim()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-trim) method

```
String s1="  hello string   ";  
System.out.println(s1.trim());
```

#### EDIT

`trim()` method only removes leading and trailing white spaces. If you want to remove spaces between words like `Mel on`, you can use the [replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    String[] list ={"Apple ",  "Mel on", "  Ice -cream ", "Television"};
        
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = list[i].replaceAll(" ", "");
    }
        
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Apple
Melon
Ice-cream
Television
```

Comment: that will only get rid of leading and trailing spaces

Comment: OP didn't mention if he wants to remove spaces between words but anyways will edit my answer

Comment: He gave `Mel on` as an example

Comment: Right... Edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

For a single string:

```
String str = "look!   Spaces!  ";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(" ","")); //Will print "look!Spaces!"
```

For an array:

```
String[] arr = ...
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

Or using Java 8 streams (although this one returns a `List`, not an array):

```
String[] arr = ...
List<String> l = Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> i.replaceAll(" ", "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```